# How can one check cron.log on Nitrous.io?

Tags: cron, nitrousio

We are attempting to implement a cron job, on Nitrous.io.  However, cron is not working.

Entry is present in the crontab.  However  we are unable to check cron.log and to find cron.log

What is a way to check cron.log, using Nitrous.io?

and

Is there any service to start and stop cron on nitrous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron by default logs to syslog, which is not accessible for [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io) users. You will want to log the command output to a custom file instead.

Here is a quick example of how to log a ping request on a Nitrous.IO box:

Navigate to the workspace folder and create a new log file called `cron.log`:

```
$ cd ~/workspace

$ touch cron.log
```

Edit your crontab to run the ping command every minute:

```
$ crontab -e
```

This will open up Vim. Add the following into line 1 and save the file:

```
* * * * * /bin/ping -c 1 192.168.0.1 > /home/action/workspace/cron.log
```

Check the contents after a minute to see if the log has been populated.

```
$ cat ~/workspace/cron.log
```